# Get peak memory in multiprocess application (C++ Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, memory, multiprocessing

I need to get total used memory (peak memory) in my multiprocess application. Since the main process releases several processes during its life, I can't just check the main process's /proc/pid/status, it doesn't sum up the memory of child processes.

One way of doing this is to release a monitoring thread which will track memory usage of all processes and give the peak memory at the end. 
But this approach has flaws: the solution is ugly; how often to monitor vmsizes? 10 miliseconds?; this not going to work on AIX system, it doesn't support /proc/pid/status interface (but I can deal with it, providing not exact memory usage on AIX platform).

Comment: did you try to use massif, a tool that uses valgrind?

Comment: Sorry I was not specific in my question. I need to report the peak memory of regular run in the log, this is my application's feature.